# How can I change color in Calendar dates?

Tags: android, colors, calendar

I want change the color of a  particular date in an Android Calendar Control.

Actually the date comes from an SQLite database. I am displaying a static date Control.

How can I do this?

Comment: how can i change color of the Saturdays and Sundays in calender conrol?